# Is there a way in windows 7 to make a flash drive use the same drive letter regardless of port?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

So at my work, we are allowed to bring music in on thumb drives and listen to it, but for legal ownership reasons, we are not allowed to store local copies on the computers hard drive, and we are *discouraged* from leaving thumb drives in perpetually. Due to this, I have mounted my thumb drive in a folder on my C drive and mapped that folder to my music library. This allows me to plug in my thumb drive, and viola, windows media player recognizes all my music as part of my library. It catalogs it and stores it, which is very nice.

The problem is, sometimes I don't plug my thumb drive into the same port. This wipes out my music references and I have to reconfigure it to map the thumb drive again to the same folder. So my question is, is there some way I can get a drive to map to a specific drive letter, if that letter is available, no matter what port it is plugged into?

Comment: You can assign a letter to a drive. Is this what you want?  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to expand upon my comment. According to this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/96298/assign-a-static-drive-letter-to-a-usb-drive-in-windows-7/), if you assign a drive letter to a USB it will try to use the same letter next time, provided it is available. To ensure that you get the same drive letter, it is recommended that you use a letter M-Z.

Open **Windows Explorer**, right click on **Computer** in the left pane, and select **Manage**. This will open **Computer Management**. Under **Storage** on the left side, go to **Disk Management**.

You can also access this through **Control Panel**. Instructions are in the Microsoft link comment on the question.

Now just right click the volume you want and select **Change Drive Letter and Paths...**, then select **Change**. Assign a new letter, preferably **M**-**Z** and click OK. Now you should be good to go.